# How to detect site listing in DMOZ directory from PHP

Tags: php, detect, dmoz

How can I detect if particular site is listend in DMOZ directory from PHP ?

Comment: Check http://dmoz-api.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

Well , I don't know if it's legal but since there is no "nice" way to do it you can
get the content of the page: http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=www.domain.com
and then search for the string "domain.com".

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Another way , you can use curl.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old question, but still may be useful to someone, there is a api service at [DMOZ API](https://www.mashape.com/nutpan/dmoz), may be useful